Confusion about reasoning of black sodium flames
This video explains that a sodium flame absorbing the 590 nm wavelength looks black under a sodium lamp. Or to be more precise, the flame looks way less orange than the orange surroundings, since the flame re-emits 590nm wavelength but in a more scattered fashion, therefore less 590nm photons reaching the camera from the flame compared to the amount of 590nm photons from the surroundings.
This way of reasoning leads to a contradicting conclusion about a sodium flame in a natural light environment with a white background wall.
Since natural light contains other wavelenghts, the sodium electrons in the flame should only absorb the 590nm wavelength and let all other wavelengths pass through towards the camera.
This should make the flame show all the other wavelengths plus a bit of 590nm (since the flame re-emits scattered 590nm photons according to above reasoning).
Therefore, the flame should then be white-ish but with a bit less 590nm photons.
And yet, sodium flame in a natural light environment clearly shows an orange color instead.
What's wrong in this reasoning?

Well, the flame emits its own light in addition to the "natural" light from the surroundings.

@d_b Emitting its own light wasn't apparently enough to be equally orange as the surroundings under the sodium lamp. So are you saying that natural light contains less intensity of 590nm photons than a sodium lamp such that the flame's own light emits more 590nm photons than what natural light contains? This should mean this amount overcompensates the scatter of 590nm photons out of the natural light that pass through the flame, right?
